# MacOS X: Missing File & Data Dictionary

Tags: filesystems, osx

After I cancelled syncronization between my Mac and MEGA, my local target dictionary became empty. However, after I used `du` to acquire the disk status, I found my data are moved to `./.debris/2016-07-22/...`. I tried `chflags nohidden ./.debris/` to cancel the hidden status for `./.debris/` but the system still told me that `chflags: ./.debris/: No such file or directory`. Now how can I do to save my files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `.debris` is not hidden because of the flag, but because it contains `.` in the front. Such files and directories in Unix-based systems are considered hidden, and by default are not displayed in OS X GUI (and regular CLI `ls` command).

You can try just to move the subdirectory `2016-07-22` outside of the hidden directory:

```
mv -i ./.debris/2016-07-22 ~/2016-07-22
```

or rename the `.debris` directory with:

```
mv -i .debris debris
```

---

The error `chflags: ./.debris/: No such file or directory` is however strange, maybe you were executing `chflags` from a different directory. To be 100% sure, use absolute paths.

I guess your `.debris` is in your home directory, so you can use a `~` (tilde):

```
mv -i ~/.debris/2016-07-22 ~/2016-07-22
```

or

```
mv -i ~/.debris ~/debris
```

---

The `-i` flag protects you against overwriting (and losing) files if the destination directory existed. It's not likely, but better stay safe.

Comment: It works and thanks! Also, I just found that `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` ; `killall Finder` can show the directory also.